# How do I access a value in a child component in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vcode is in a child component.

```
data() {
    return {
      vcode: null,
    };
  },
```

I need to access this value in a parent component method.

```
verifyCode() {
   const code = this.vcode
}
```

Attempting this returns undefined. How do I access this value?

**Update**

I tried the suggestions and I still get an undefined value

Input field on child component

```
 <input
          class="form-control mt-5"
          v-model.trim="vcode"
          :class="{'is-invalid' : $v.vcode.$error }"
          @input="$v.vcode.$touch(), vcodenum = $event.target.value"
          placeholder="Enter your 6 digit code"
        />
```

On the parent component I added the following where it references the child component

```
<step2 ref="step2" @on-validate="mergePartialModels" v-on:vcodenum="vcode = $event"></step2>
```

My method in the parent component

```
verifyCode() {
   const code = this.vcode
   console.log(code)
}
```

I still get undefined.

**I also tried this:**

Child component

```
    <input
      class="form-control mt-5"
      v-model.trim="vcode"
      :class="{ 'is-invalid': $v.vcode.$error }"
      @input="$v.vcode.$touch(), onInput"
      placeholder="Enter your 6 digit code"
    />
```

Props

```
  props: {
    value: {
      type: [String, Number, Boolean],
      default: "",
    },
  },
```

method

```
onInput(e) {
      this.$emit('on-input', e.target.value)
    },
```

Parent

```
 <step2 ref="step2" @on-validate="mergePartialModels" :value="vcode" @on-input="handleInput"></step2>

  data() {
    return {
      vcode: null
    };
  },
```

method

```
  handleInput(value) {
    this.vcode = value
    console.log(this.vcode)
  },
```

The value ends up outputting null.
If I use the v-bind I get this error:
:value="value" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen to the child's input event and send the value to the parent.

```
// InputComponent.vue

<input :value="value" @input="onInput" />

....
props: {
  value: {
    type: [String, Number, Boolean] // Add any custom types,
    default: ''
  }
},
methods: {
  onInput(e) {
    this.$emit('on-input', e.target.value)
  }
}


// Parent.vue
<InputComponent :value="vCode" @on-input="handleInput" />
....
data() {
  return {
    vcode: null
  }
},
methods: {
  handleInput(value) {
    this.vode = value
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the following error when attempting to use this: :value="value" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally <input class="form-control mt-5" v-model.trim="vcode" :class="{ 'is-invalid': $v.vcode.$error }" @input="$v.vcode.$touch(), onInput" :value="value" placeholder="Enter your 6 digit code" /> Parent - <step2 ref="step2" @on-validate="mergePartialModels" :value="vcode" @on-input="handleInput"></step2>

Comment: I think its because I need to remove the v-model. But I also need it to run $v.vcode.$touch() on input. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, v-model is not required when you're using value. It throws the above error if we do that.

Comment: Ok, but that breaks my validation because I need to include v-model.trim="vcode" @input="$v.vcode.$touch()," this some how in my input field